# Spacy - modify tokenizer for numeric patterns

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy

I have seen some ways to create a custom tokenizer, but I am a little confused. What I am doing is using the Phrase Matcher to match patterns. However, it would match a 4-digit number pattern, say `1234`, in `111-111-1234`, since it splits on the dash.

All I want to do is modify the current tokenizer (from `nlp = English()`) and add a rule that it should not split on some characters but only for numeric patterns.

Comment: Can you add a few inputs and expected outputs as examples?

Comment: For example, `111-111-1234` should be `111-111-1234` -- it should not be split on the `-`. Also, would like to add split if word goes from lower to upper case: `abcDE` would become `['abc','DE']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to overwrite spaCy's default `infix` tokenization scheme with your own. You can do this by modifying the infix tokenization scheme used by spaCy found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/punctuation.py).

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA, ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER, HYPHENS
from spacy.lang.char_classes import CONCAT_QUOTES, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_ICONS
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex

# default tokenizer
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("111-222-1234 for abcDE")
print([t.text for t in doc])

# modify tokenizer infix patterns
infixes = (
        LIST_ELLIPSES
        + LIST_ICONS
        + [
            r"(?<=[0-9])[+\*^](?=[0-9-])", # Remove the hyphen
            r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\.?(?=[{au}{q}])".format( # Make the dot optional
                al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
            )
            ,
            r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
            r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
            r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        ]
)

infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer
doc = nlp("111-222-1234 for abcDE")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

**Output**

```sh
With default tokenizer:
['111', '-', '222', '-', '1234', 'for', 'abcDE']

With custom tokenizer:
['111-222-1234', 'for', 'abc', 'DE']
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this can be edited for this: I don't wanted to split `RE:` into `['RE',':']`. In other words, if there is an 'RE' followed by a colon, don't split. Can that be added here by modifying one of these infixes?